# Stardog: How to pass parameters to SPARQL stored query over http protocol

Tags: api, http, sparql, semantic-web, stardog

I am new to semantic web and SPARQL. I am trying to do a get request over HTTP protocol while passing parameters in my URL. How do I put the parameter in my SPARQL query and how do I give a value to it my URL.

Following is what I have:

Sparql query: (I am trying to put my value to the s)

```
values($employeeId) {(<$s>)}
```

http request:

```
https://stardog-server-test/Profil/query?query=alphonsoTest&$s='"105A203"'
```

Like you can see, I am trying to give the value `105A203`.

I want my method to be `GET` with no payload/body.

Comment: is the `employeeId` supposed to be a URI or literal? In your query you used the variable inside `<>` so it has to be a URI, just doing then `query?query=alphonsoTest&$s='"105A203"'` gives a string literal `"105A203"` as argument. That can't be correct. First, adapt the query template to `values values($employeeId) {($s)}` and then if it is a URI do `query?query=alphonsoTest&$s=<some:URI>`, otherwise use the request you already have with `"105A203"`

Comment: @AKSW , the employeeId needs to be a litteral. My error is in the query. Stardog does not recognize ($s) as a variable.

Comment: yeah,  `values($employeeId) {($s)}` - that doesn't work.  I think SPARQL doesn't allow variables in `VALUES` clause because that doesn't make sense in this position, it expects only RDF terms (URIs, literals) or `UNDEF`.  you should ask on the Stardog mailing list if there is some workaround - you'll get support very fast by people that know Stardog much better than me.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you don't actually need VALUES. Stardog lets you pass bind values directly for variables (ones that start with $, anyway) via additional query string parameters much like the way you're already trying:

```
GET http://stardog-server:5820/myDb/query?query=select * where {?s ?p $myO}&$myO="105A203"
```

If you have saved `select * where {?s ?p $myO}` as a stored query, then using the stored query's name also works:

```
GET http://stardog-server:5820/myDb/query?query=myQuery&$myO="105A203"
```

Feel free to post any further questions in [the Stardog community forum](https://community.stardog.com/)